# Evaluation of an integral of a particular form

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate an integral of this form:
 $$ \iint_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}  \max\{x,y\}\,dx dy $$?

Please give  the approach to  help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x$. Then tthe domain of integration of $y$ is naturally separated in two
parts. This leads to:
$$
\int_{[0,1]×[0,1]}\max\{x,y\}dxdy = \int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=0}^x x dy + \int_{y=x}^1 y dy
\right) dx
$$

Comment: which is about the same as to evaluate just one of the integrals, below the diagonal $y=x$, and then multiply the result by $2$, using symmetry

Comment: yes, but it is a general strategy: cut the domain of integration in pieces to simplify what is inside the integral.